# Thinning/Skeletenization is distorting my image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am trying to thin this image but it keeps getting distorted.

[image]

[image]

This is my relevant code for applying the thinning. I have also tried the 'thin' function instead of 'skeletonize' but the results are similar.

```
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize, thin
new_im = cv2.imread(im_pth)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(new_im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ske = (skeletonize(gray//255) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow("image", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

My goal is to get a shape similar to this after thinning:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I have read online that sometimes jpg files cause issues however I don't have the experience in this field to confirm that.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if your conversion from input image to binary is correct.  Here's a version using scikit-image functions that seems to do what you want:

```
from skimage import img_as_float
from skimage import io, color, morphology
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = img_as_float(color.rgb2gray(io.imread('char.png')))
image_binary = image < 0.5
out_skeletonize = morphology.skeletonize(image_binary)
out_thin = morphology.thin(image_binary)


f, (ax0, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10, 3))

ax0.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
ax0.set_title('Input')

ax1.imshow(out_skeletonize, cmap='gray')
ax1.set_title('Skeletonize')

ax2.imshow(out_thin, cmap='gray')
ax2.set_title('Thin')

plt.savefig('/tmp/char_out.png')
plt.show()
```

[image: skeletonization and thinning in skimage]

Answer (score 1):

From your example, and since your image is binary, I think that what you want to do is better achieved via (binary) erosion. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)) explains the concept well. Intuitively (in case you don't have time to read the wikipedia link), imagine you have a binary image `A`, like the one you have given, and let's call `A_1` the set of pixels of `A` that have a value of `1`. Then, you define a "structuring element" `K`, which for example can be a square patch of size `n*n`. Then in pseudocode

```
for pixel in A_1:
    center K at pixel, and call this centered version K_pixel 
    if(K_pixel is contained in A_1):
        keep pixel
    else:
        discard pixel
```

So, this has the effect of thinning the connected component in your image.

This function is standard and is implemented in opencv, [here](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/application_development/9781785283932/2/ch02lvl1sec24/erosion-and-dilation) are some python examples, and [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html) is a link to the documentation (c++).

Comment: Thanks for getting back, I was converting to grayscale but actually needed to apply adaptive thresholding before thinning! Silly me